# safe unwrap URL type

Tags: swift, url, swift-optionals

Im forming a url to pass in next to request, in return my app crashes, because it unexpectedly finds nil, when debuggin -> i do have url, so my question, how can i avoid using force unwrap here ?
when i use guard or if let, what should i return instead ? URL ? it will be optional again.
Making
`var url: URL?` not good for me also.

```
public var url: URL {
    var components = URLComponents()
    components.scheme = scheme
    components.host = ipAddress
    components.path = endpoint
    components.port = port
    components.queryItems = urlQueryItems
    return components.url!.removingPercentEncoding!
}
```

Comment: Without context, no one will be able to tell you what default value should you use for an invalid `URL`. What does this URL represent? Are the inputs dynamic? Is there a meaningful default URL you can use? If not, you need to stop the context where you'd be using the `URL` that couldn't be created.

Comment: `removingPercentEncoding` seems to be counterproductive because `URLComponents` adds percent encoding dynamically where necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Never use an exclamation mark. It *means* "crash me". You can hardly be surprised when you *do* crash, because that is precisely what you said to do.

You have no useful value to return if `components.url` turns out to be `nil`, which can definitely happen (as you have discovered). Therefore, simply change your `public var url: URL` to return `URL?` instead. Then just return `components.url`. This puts the onus on the caller to check whether `url` is `nil`, and it can proceed to unwrap safely by using the usual `if let url` dance.

Comment: Note that the `if let` dance is greatly smoothed in Xcode 14; you no longer need to say `if let url = url`.